# Android app getting error while run actual device, but it working fine with emulator

Tags: android, parse-platform, inflate-exception, back4app

im testing one of my android app and its working fine with emulator, but when i run with actual device it keep stopping with message saying open try again (emulator and actual device both api 24 and version7.0 actual device is s7).this app backend based on back4app parse. please try to solve this issue

this is the error log that im getting

```
05-22 17:26:21.519 6097-7568/? E/ActivityManager: applyOptionsLocked: 
pendingOptions.getStartX()=23pendingOptions.getStartY()=1168
05-22 17:26:21.531 1883-1883/? E/Zygote: v2
05-22 17:26:21.532 1883-1883/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
05-22 17:26:22.503 1883-1883/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: 
classify.domain.com.prinsprem, PID: 1883

java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too 
large(201326592bytes) bitmap.
at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
                                                 at 
 android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1420)
                                                 at 
 android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
 at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1286)
                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18319)
                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17297)
                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18081)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17292)
                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18081)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17292)
                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18081)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17292)
                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18081)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17292)
                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18081)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17292)
                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18081)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18322)
                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:854)
                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17297)
                                                 at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:666)
                                                 at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:672)
                                                 at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:780)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3112)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2908)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2502)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1509)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7051)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: Please use an image loading  library

Comment: `201326592bytes` is 201 megabyte large image. You can't draw it on the real device for sure. That is the problem.

Comment: Hi thanks problem solved

Answer (score 0):

This error clearly stated that you are trying to render a very large image, 
what you can do is to rescale your images by any of the image editor app to reduce its size, and copy it into your drawable folder. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Its nice, Please accept the answer if it helps you.